# Ошибка в методе шаблона класса. С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#ifndef __GEOMETRY
#define __GEOMETRY
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define PI 3.14159265


template <typename T>
struct Vec2
{
    union {
        struct { T x, y; };
        T raw[2];
    };
    Vec2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vec2(T _x, T _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
    Vec2(const Vec2<T> &vec): x(vec.x), y(vec.y){}

    operator Vec2<int>() { return Vec2<int>(x + 0.5, y + 0.5); }
    operator Vec2<float>() { return Vec2<float>(x, y); }
    Vec2<T> operator +  (const Vec2<T> &vec) { return Vec2<T>(x + vec.x, y + vec.y); }
    Vec2<T> operator -  (const Vec2<T> &vec) { return Vec2<T>(x - vec.x, y - vec.y); }
    Vec2<T> operator *  (const float value) { return Vec2<T>(x*value, y*value); }
    Vec2<T> operator /  (const T value) { return Vec2<T>(x / value, y / value); }


    double       operator *  (const Vec2<T> &vec) { return x * vec.x + y * vec.y; }
    T       operator [] (int index) { if (index == 0) return x; else return y; }


    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& ostr, const Vec2<T> &vec) {
        ostr << "Vector: " << vec.x << " " << vec.y;
        return ostr;
    }

    double length() { return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); }
    double angle() { return acos(x / length()) * 180 / PI; }
    double angle_to(const Vec2<T> &vec) { return vec.length(); } 
  /* Выдает ошибку  из-за того что я пишу "vec.length()"
Ошибка  C2662   double Vec2<float>::length(void): невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const Vec2<float>" в "Vec2<float> &"    */

};
typedef Vec2<float> Vec2f
#endif 


//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "geo.h"

int main()
{

  Vec2f test(2,4);
  std::cout << test.angle_to(Vec2f(1,0));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Vec2f test(2,4);` - у вас вообще нет `Vec2f`...

Comment: Не все скопировал, прошу прощения. У меня есть `typedef Vec2<float> Vec2f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константные функции лучше делать константными:

```
double length() const { return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); }
double angle() const { return acos(x / length()) * 180 / PI; }
double angle_to(const Vec2<T> &vec) const { return vec.length(); }
```

Обратите внимание на `const`. Кстати, последняя вообще не использует данные объекта - она точно не должна быть статической?..

Я указал только некоторые функции, но вы проверьте все - если они не меняют состояние объекта - объявляйте их как константные...

И все же решите, вы используете `Vec2` или `Vec2f`...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90793/discussion-on-answer-by-harry------).